# Cordova Image Upload Duplicate Issue

Tags: android, cordova, file-upload, android-camera, cordova-plugins

I'm encountering a very weird phenomenon while uploading files from my Cordova app to the server.

My app allows users to select 2 images (from album / camera) using navigator.camera.getPicture, then retrieves the Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, which is later used for uploading via the FileTransfer plugin, sending the file to server in sequence.

Now, the weird problem is, 5 - 10% of the time, the 2 photos uploaded by our Android app users ended up with BOTH being the second photo. That means, after user selected photo 1 and 2, and uploaded both, the server end received the images as both being photo 2.

We've tried asking as much info from users as possible, and we narrowed it down to an issue with Android (works perfectly on iOS). It is most likely not a connection issue, as users had this problem whether on Wifi or 3G, and we're not sure if it's a memory issue, since some newer models encountered this problem as well.

We tried many times but could not replicate this problem with our Android devices (including slower, older ones).

Is there anyone that came across such a weird issue, and is this a problem with the Camera plugin or File Transfer plugin? I'm suspecting it has to do with memory problem, where somehow the app lost or mixed up the file URIs before uploading.

The problem only happens one way - as in BOTH photos became photo 2, but never both becoming photo 1.

Please advise, thanks!

[UPDATE]

I'm noticing a weird phenomenon upon displaying the FILE_URI value passed by getPicture. If I call the getPicture again for the second image, the cache file used by the plugin remains the same. It's always "file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.myapp/cache/modified.jpg?242432424" (the ending digits are random, but it is ALWAYS "modified.jpg" filename).

This results in the second image overwriting the first one. However, I haven't figured out how most of the time the app successfully uploads 2 separate images instead of same duplicate.

Is this a plugin bug, always using the same filename as the cached image, and could it be related to some phone memory problem? Is there any way to make it use random file names, instead of just appending random parameters to the same file?

My Android is 4.3.1, running Cordova 3.6.

Below is the getPicture code I am using:

```
        navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageData) { uploadPhoto(imageData) }, onCameraFail, {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, allowEdit: false, correctOrientation: true, saveToPhotoAlbum: false, targetWidth: 1280, targetHeight: 960
        });
```

Comment: The problem is probably in your javascript code - maybe you could post the part where you do the uploading.

Comment: I have just added the Javascript code, can you please have a look? Thank you.

Comment: I just discovered that the weird bug may related to getPicture of the Camera plugin, and updated it to show my getPicture Javascript instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 2.1.0 of the camera plugin has already solved that bug.
The patch was applied 16 Oct 2015.

Upgrading the plugin solved the bug in my case at least.

Answer (score 3):

I've been dealing with the same issue as well. The issue has to do with the the cordova-camera-plugin not returning the real path. Instead it returns the path to the cached modified file. After trying out all the solutions out there including modifying the heck out of CameraLauncher.java and FileHelper.java, I ended up using an entirely different plugin (https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker) for choosing images from the gallery while using the cordova-camera-plugin strictly just for the camera.

This plugin worked out quite nicely as it solved the cached path issue and on top of that, users are able to choose 1 to multiple images and also presented a better experience for the user when choosing images on android.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it out!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a bug with Cordova's Camera plugin. If you call getPicture with some modification parameters like changing of width or height, the plugin automatically creates a new image file, BUT... the created file is universally called "modified.jpg".

So, within the same instance, if I have two or more calls to getPicture with image modification parameters, all the subsequent images are stored under the same name in Cordova's cache folder, thus OVERWRITING the earlier ones.

There appears to be no way to set the modified image's file name. The workaround I made was to NOT resize one of the images, so the original system image filename was retained. I was originally using resizing for both images to reduce the upload time and bandwidth required.

Hopefully Cordova fixes Camera plugin problem in subsequent releases.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue and keeping an eye out at this question, which pointed me into a possible solution.

There is a fix waiting to be added. Here is the link to the details https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/pull/99. See changes in the files changed tab.

As a work around, I upload the image as soon as they select it, so it doesn't matter if the local name is the same. I create the file name via a php function.

As far as usability goes this actually improves the process of selecting multiple images as the user only waits a tiny bit for one image to upload. I disable the image select buttons while an upload is happening to stop duplicates happening.

Comment: Thank you.. your answer should theoretically fix the file name issue, if that's the only location defining the file name. Could it be the earlier compiled plugin classes need to be cleaned first?

Comment: I've had a look through and it looks like there are only two places where the file name is set when modified. I have also noticed that my file name changes are not pulling through. Even when i make obvious changes they don't happen. Sorry I couldn't help. I'm in desperate need for this to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for trying.. perhaps you could submit a bug report to the developer of the camera plugin? For now I temporarily made a workaround whereby I am only resizing one of the two photos, so there is no conflict of filenames.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem as follows, I have helped =)

1 - Find the file: path-to-your-app/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/camera/CameraLauncher.java

2 - Import the classes, at the top of the file:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.math.BigInteger;
```

3 - Search for "modified.jpg" and replace with:

```
String randomName = new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);
String modifiedPath = getTempDirectoryPath() + "/" + randomName + "_modified.jpg";
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the fix! According to another reply, you can also upgrade to the latest plugin version to resolve the problem.

Comment: About upgrading to the latest version of the plugin, I do not know if I understand correctly. I'm using cordova 4.0 and installed the plugin via the command line, so this would be the latest version of the plugin, right?
Thank you!